# Return collection of one without "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a SearchController where I check a search term against two tables, first for exact matches (followed by a redirect table to the relevant manufacturer page) and then for partial matches - four conditions in total. All of these conditions work except the last one, probably because it often needs to return just one result inside of a collection.

I need this to be the case as I would like to do `$results->slug`, `$results->name`, etc. throughout the view no matter which search condition is being triggered. Currently I'm able to do this to access the search results of all the conditions except the third one.

Search Controller class, where everything but the third condition is working as it should:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
        public function index() {
            if (request("search")) {

            # Works as expected
            $exact_terms = SearchTerm::with("manufacturer")->where('term', request("search"))->get();
            if($exact_terms->isNotEmpty()) {
                echo "Exact search term match!";
                $results = $exact_terms;

                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $slug = $result->manufacturer->slug;
                }

                return redirect()->action([ManufacturerController::class, 'index'], ["manufacturer" => $slug]); 
            }

            # Works as expected
            $exact_make = Manufacturer::where('slug', request("search"))->get();
            if($exact_make->isNotEmpty()) {
                echo "Exact manufacturer match!";
                $results = $exact_make;

                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $slug = $result->slug;
                }
                return redirect()->action([ManufacturerController::class, 'index'], ["manufacturer" => $slug]); 
            }

            # Doesn't work
            $search_terms = SearchTerm::with("manufacturer")->where('term', "like", '%' . request("search") . '%')->get()->unique("manufacturers");
            if($search_terms->isNotEmpty()) {
                echo "Search term match!";
                foreach ($search_terms as $search_term) {
                    $search_term = $search_term->manufacturer;
                }
                $results = collect($search_term);
            } 

            # Works as expected
            $search_make = Manufacturer::where('slug', 'like', '%' . request("search") . '%')->get();
            if($search_make->isNotEmpty()) {
                echo "Manufacturer match!";
                $results = $search_make;
            }

        $results = isset($results) ? $results : collect();
        }
        
        return view("search", [
        "manufacturer" => $manufacturer,
        "results" => $results,
    ]);
    }
}
```

View file:

```
@if($results)
       
<h1 class="my-5"> {{ $results->count() }} {{ $results->count() == 1 ? "result" : "results" }} found for <i>{{ request("search") }}</i></h1>

@foreach ($results as $result)

{{ $result->slug }}

@endforeach    
@else
<p><h1>Sorry! We couldn't find any results for <i>"{{ request("search") }}"</i>.</h1></p>
@endif
```

Result of a `dd($results)` when triggering the condition just before the `foreach` loop:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1406 ▼
#items: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 15
    "slug" => "ford"
    "name" => "Ford"
    "created_at" => "2022-01-28T19:53:28.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-01-28T19:53:28.000000Z"
]
#escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Result of a `dd($result)` when triggering the condition inside of the `foreach` loop (shows nothing from the array but the primary key):

```
15
```

Comment: you don't have a Collection of Models, you have a Collection that is holding what looks like the attributes of a single Model, just an array of attributes ... you are overwriting `$search_term` every iteration of that `foreach` loop ... then you are putting just that one thing into a collection

Comment: @lagbox Yes, it's a collection of 1 model, or at least should be. The result of the query is often just one object, and I attempted to place that object into a collection to be able to `foreach` through it on the view like I can with the rest of my search queries.

Comment: if you are expecting 1 single item why would you need a collection or to use a loop? use `first` instead of `get` and check if the result is `null` or not ... unless there is the potential for more than 1 result

Comment: For the reasons that I've explained twice now, both in my last comment and the body of the question. And yes, the search query due to `unique()` doesn't and shouldn't always return a single result, just more often.

Comment: `$search_term->manufacturer` should be returning a Model object not an array, so not sure why your Collection is only holding the attributes and not the actual object, so it would seem there is other code not being shown that could be causing this result

Comment: @lagbox I thought it was clear from the question body and the comments in the code, but evidently not, so I've now added the other three working conditions that I originally removed to make the question body more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a Model to a Collection via the constructor, it will end up pulling the attributes from it since Model is `Arrayable` (it will call `toArray` on it and get the attributes/appends/relationships as an array). You could call `add` on the Collection to add the Model.

```
$results = collect()->add($search_term);
```

Or you can pass an array to `collect` which it is expecting:

```
$results = collect([$search_term]);
```

On a side note, you are doing a lot of iterating to just get the last value from a Collection to use in all of these conditions. You could call `last` on the Collection to get the last value, or even restrict your query to return a single result instead of an entire result set since you are literally not using any of the result set except the last record.

Comment: `add()` works perfectly, weird that it's not in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

Comment: either that or you would have to wrap the model in an array, `collect([$search_term])` ... it makes sense why the constructor does what it does ... you are supposed to be giving it a "collection" of data (array), not a single item, so it assumes since Model is `Arrayable` that it is that "collection" of data